# Where does sshd default configuration come from?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, configuration, openssh

After a fresh install every option of the default configuration file in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** commented out. But when I run `/usr/sbin/sshd -tT`, there are many option actually to see.

Where are those came from?

**Related:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570371/sshd-config-all-parameters-commented-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even with an empty `sshd` configuration file, sshd has a default set of options that it will use out-of-the-box. To see learn more about these options, run `man sshd_config`. The page has the options (keywords) available, and often, what the default values are.

The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is provided with these default options commented out to make the job of the system admin easier.